# TableView won't show cells content

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have a TableViewCell subclass and I am trying to create a table with this cell type. However the table won't show the custom cells content.
The values of the cell derive from data core model. But there isn't an issue with it as I have also tried with simple literals and it still wouldn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

**favCell.m**

```
#import "favCell.h"

@implementation favCell

@synthesize view;
@synthesize namelbl;
@synthesize scorelbl;
@synthesize prodimage;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {


        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        [self addSubview:view];

        // initiate

        prodimage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2,20, 20, 20)];
        namelbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,20, 40, 40)];
        scorelbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70,20, 30, 30)];


        [view addSubview:namelbl];
        [view addSubview:scorelbl];
        [view addSubview:prodimage];




    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

**favTable.m**

```
#import "favTable.h"
#import "ecoAppDelegate.h"
#import "favCell.h"

@interface favTable ()

@end

@implementation favTable

@synthesize favArr;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize favName;
@synthesize favScore;



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    favCell*cell = (favCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[favCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }



    cell.namelbl.text = [favName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.scorelbl.text = [favScore objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.prodimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test1.jpg"];



    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This `[UITableViewCell namelbl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` says that the cells you are working with are plain `UITableViewCell` instances rather than `favCell`.  Somewhere in your table design you're not setting the right cell type or identifier.

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes you are right. Just changed the class of my prototype cell to the custom subclass. However the content of the cell still won't show up

Comment: try using "[self.contentView addSubview:view];" insted of "[self addSubview:view];"

Comment: @Student nope it didn't make a difference

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and see what the values are that you're assigning and the objects that you are assigning to.

Comment: @PhillipMills updated the post with the picture of it

Comment: The picture doesn't really help…you want to step through and examine the values/objects that are being used and updated as you go.